# After Importing Android Project into Eclipse, Package Icons are "white"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide

I just imported a sample project into Eclipse and some of the icons are white:

[image]

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

UPDATE:

[image: 'empty' packages have files]

Comment: If I remember correct, that is how eclipse shows empty packages.

Comment: But these aren't empty. They have files in them.

Comment: Try to expend menu of the project manager (little trianagle next to the arrows) and in 'Package Presentation' make sure you checked 'Flat'

Comment: @jlordo, I'm not seeing any. I think the white icons should be folders, not src packages

Comment: @MarcinS. I'm not clear on what you are saying. I don't see any arrows. I see the triangles; but, again, no arrows, or 'package presentation'

Comment: Look at the screenshot you have posted. There are icons on the right top corner.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! And they are flat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that I had to add the folders to the project for some reason; why, I don't know. What I do know is that it worked.

To do this you Right click on the project > Build Path > Configure Build Path > Source > Add folders > click on Gen & src

Comment: Gen*Src, I don't see it

Answer (score 1):

A white package is a package which is not empty but contains no source files.  Empty packages are not shown, and packages with source are brown.

Answer (score 0):

White packages can also denote a package that is excluded from a build.